# Itext7 - Crop Image

Tags: itext7

Hi How can we resize image in iText 7 . 
I am not able to find PDFTemplate in itext 7 now which used to crop image.
.

```
public Image cropImage(PdfWriter writer, Image image, float leftReduction, float rightReduction, float topReduction, float bottomReduction) throws DocumentException {
    float width = image.getScaledWidth();
    float height = image.getScaledHeight();
    PdfTemplate template = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(
            width - leftReduction - rightReduction,
            height - topReduction - bottomReduction);
    template.addImage(image,
            width, 0, 0,
            height, -leftReduction, -bottomReduction);
    return Image.getInstance(template);
}
```

This is used for itext 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you have this image, measuring 900 x 1200 pixels:

[image]

But you only want to show part of this image (e.g. the ping pong balls):

[image]

Then you can use this iText 7 code:

```java
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("cropimage.pdf"));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
Image image = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(imagePath));
image.setFixedPosition(-20, -320);
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(300, 300);
PdfFormXObject template = new PdfFormXObject(rectangle);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(template, pdf);
canvas.add(image);
Image croppedImage = new Image(template);
document.add(croppedImage);
document.close();
```

We create an `Image` instance with the full image, and we set the fixed position in such a way that we chip off 20 pixels from the left, and 320 from the bottom.

We create a rectangle of 300 x 300 user units. This defines the size of the cropped image.

We create a `PdfFormXObject` using this rectangle. In iText 5 language, a Form XObject used to be named a `PdfTemplate`.

We create a `Canvas` object with this `template`, and we add the image to the `canvas`.

Finally, we create another `Image` using the template. The `Canvas` operation will have added the full image to that `template`, but it will be cropped to the size of the `rectangle`.

You can add this `croppedImage` to the document.

Comment: Thanks let me check :)